# RegEx backreference modification in AutoHotkey possible?

Tags: regex, autohotkey, backreference

I'd like to modify a backreference in RegExReplace before using it.

I want to make something like this work:

```
RegExReplace(ManualTimeValues, "(\d+)\.(\d+)", "$1"*60+"$2")
```

`ManualTimeValues` is a line containing numbers in integer and floating point format, separated by spaces. I want to replace the floating point numbers with integers computed by multiplying the part before the point with 60 and adding the part after the point.
I've also tried :

```
RegExReplace(ManualTimeValues, "\d+\.\d+", min2sec("$0"))
```

with `min2sec` being a custom function that converts a single floating point number.
I've also tried the same lines with unquoted backreferences.

I've solved this in practice using

```
Loop, Parse, ManualTimevalues, %A_Space%
```

but is there a way to use RegExReplace for this?

Comment: With the built-in function, probably no but I've seen a UDF for regex callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using AutoHotkey_L (and if you're not, you should be), search for "Regular Expression Callouts" in the index.  That will allow you to do what you're looking for, although your loop, parse is just as good in this case.